# Same App, Same OS, But Different UI elements in OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, cocoa, applescript

I've inspected an application with both built-in accessibility inspector and UI Browser, the commercial app.
However, in the same OS X 10.9.5 (in Macbook Pro and Mac Pro), I got totally different result.
In Macbook pro, window1 has many elements including button 14.

I have totally no idea on it.
Due to I need more reputation to post image, I'll type the difference.
Anybody know how exactly  same app shows different UI elements name and structure?

First one (proper one)

```
*Hierarchy
AXApplication
 AXWindow:AXStandardWindow
  AXButton

*Attributes
AXRole : AXButton
AXRoleDescription : button
AXParent : <AXWindow:AXStandardWindow>
AXWindow : <AXWindow:AXStandardWindow>
AXTolLevelUIElement <AXWindow:AXStandardWindow>
AXPosition : x=157.00 y=184.00
AXSize : w=22.00 h=22.00
AXEnabled NO
AXDescription Click this to select the closest following event

*Actions
AXPress
```

And Second one (weird one)

```
*Hierarchy
AXApplication
 AXWindow:AXStandardWindow
  AXUnknown
   AXUnknown
    AXUnknown
     AXUnknown
*Attributes
AXRole : AXUnknown
AXRoleDescription : unknown
AXParent : <AXUnknown>
AXWindow : <AXWindow:AXStandardWindow>
AXTolLevelUIElement <AXWindow:AXStandardWindow>
AXPosition : x=157.00 y=184.00
AXSize : w=22.00 h=22.00
AXEnabled YES
```

Comment: Zaph, the above results are from same tool (UI Browser)

Answer (score 0):

I clean installed new VM with Mavericks and Yosemite, and tried several experiments from starting point.
Still have no explanation about the mechanism, but:

1. with Xcode 5.1 and command-line tool of that version, all elements shown its proper name (button #, window # etc).
2. However, when Xcode 6 and command-line tool of newest version solely installed, elements are not shown properly.

Another required / sufficient possibility is install of CANOPY and its all QT-related free plugin.